# Magento 2 code not adding more than 1 link to top nav

Tags: php, magento2

I have the following php code to add non category links to the top nav. It adds one of the menu items "Test page" but won't add "Test page2". So I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong in this case. Any ideas?

```
<?php
namespace testMod\navUpdate\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class Topmenu implements ObserverInterface
{

/**
 * @param EventObserver $observer
 * @return $this
 */
public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $menu */
    $menu = $observer->getMenu();
    $tree = $menu->getTree();
    $data = [
        'name'      => __('Test page'),
        'id'        => 'test-page',
        'url'       => 'test-page',
    ];
    $node = new Node($data, 'id', $tree, $menu);
    $menu->addChild($node);
    return $this;
}

public function execute2(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $menu */
        $menu = $observer->getMenu();
        $tree = $menu->getTree();
        $data = [
            'name'      => __('Test page2'),
            'id'        => 'test-page2',
            'url'       => 'test-page2',
        ];
        $node = new Node($data, 'id', $tree, $menu);
        $menu->addChild($node);
        return $this;
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Solution can be found here for adding more than one link: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116523/add-more-than-1-non-category-link-to-top-nav-magento-2